# How to swap two words in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, swap

for example if I have this text

```
left left right
```

after swapping should be like that

```
right right left
```

Comment: I mean the question is i wanna swap "left" and "right" separately

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, that the words left and right from your question are only examples, and what you really want is a solution (assignable to a keyboard shortcut) that transforms pattern of `X X Y` to `Y Y X`, I would suggest recording a macro that does the transformation, then assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut:

- make sure that the cursor is behind the text, that is right to `Y`
- use Macro -> Start Recording

  1. Press Ctrl-Shift-Left
  2. Press Ctrl-X
  3. Press Backspace
  4. Press Ctrl-Shift-Left
  5. Press Delete
  6. Press Backspace
  7. Press Ctrl-Left
  8. Press Ctrl-V
  9. Press Space
  10. Press Ctrl-V
  11. Press Space
  12. Press Ctrl-Right
- Use Macro -> Stop Recording
- Use Macro -> Save Current recorded Macro

  - give it a name
  - assign a keyboard shortcut
- now you can use the new keyboard shortcut when you are right to the third word

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl F, then navigate to replace.

There you'll see "find what:" and "replace with:"

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the answer is 6 years too late.. But I had the same issue this morning. I do not believe Notepad ++ or any other text editor has a direct answer to this. I just used the good old programming logic to swap two values..

First replace all "left" with "temp_right".

Replace all "right" with "left".

Replace all "temp_right" with "right".

Answer (score -1):

What you'll first want to do is head to the "Find and Replace" window. A quick way to do this is **Ctrl + H**. For the text to be searched (*Find What*) you would put: "left left right". What to replace it (*Replace With*) with: "right right left". Then you would press **Replace** or **Replace All**.